# Cannot resolve symbol ColorStateList

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `ColorStateList` to change the color of a `RadioGroup`, but running into some basic errors.  Can I change the color of `RadioGroup` buttons without using `ColorStateList`?  Is there an easier way?

I've imported the following and still getting 'cannot resolve symbol'.

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
```

I'm trying to implement `ColorStateList` in the below, not sure if I'm doing it correctly, but first I need to fix the 'cannot resolve symbol error':

```
if (Item.getCar()=='Audi'){
    ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
        },
        new int[] {
            Color.BLACK //disabled
            ,Color.BLUE //enabled

        }
);

int textColor = Color.parseColor("#000000");
x.radioGroup.set(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));
```

Any help in trying to get `ColorStateList` to work is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import following

```
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
```

it works for me.

Comment: Thanks.  One other issue is that it's not actually applying to radioGroup.
x.radioGroup.set(ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));